# constructor injection in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

i want to use Request class in my constructor and this is the error it gives to me while i want to run server:

> Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Controller\DetectServiceDetailController": argument "$request" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" but no such service exists. It cannot be auto-registered because it is from a different root namespace.

my code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DetectServiceDetailController
{
    public $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $serviceType = $this->request->query->get('type');
        return $serviceType;

    }

}
```

Comment: symfony 3 or 4?

Comment: Anyway you should inject the `RequestStack` class instead of `Request`.

Comment: @AlexKarshin 3.4

Comment: @gp_sflover why?! i want to get query string with that.it doesnt have query->get()

Comment: consider moving to 4, it's faster and smarter. There's a detailed manual in docs on how to upgrade. Your life will become easier, trust me.

Comment: @sina read [How to Retrieve the Request from the Service Container](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/request.html) and [API Reference](https://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RequestStack.html)

Comment: @gp_sflover except sina is doing this in a controller, not just some service...

Comment: @AlexKarshin the best pratice is to inject only what you need in a service (_and controllers are also "services" in symfony4_). My comments wants to be only general tips and nothing more :-).

Comment: @gp_sflover Don't get offended :) Yes, best practice is to inject only what you need and even better *when* you need it, that's why in our team we inject `Request` right into controller methods.

Comment: @gp_sflover It's accepted best practice in Symfony to [pass `Request` as a controller argument](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument).

Comment: You need to extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` !!

Comment: @gp_sflover Could you please add an answer with the `RequestStack`?

Answer (score 7):

As per gp_sflover's suggestion here is a piece of code I use in Symfony 3.4:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }

    ...
```

In my case BaseController extends Controller so I don't need to update services.yml, but if this is stand alone service  then you need to add it to services.yml e.g.

```
services:
    ...
    service_name:
        class: AppBundle\Service\ServiceName
        arguments:
            - '@request_stack'
        public: true
```

Just adding it for less experienced devs ;-)